# C# on linux: FFmpeg (FFMediaToolkit) on linux System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Cannot found the default FFmpeg directory

Tags: c#, linux, dll, ffmpeg, nuget

I have C# project in rider and `FFMediaToolkit` installed via *NuGet*. I made instance of `MediaBuilder`. When I hit run I get this error message:

```
/home/john/Projects/Slimulator/bin/Debug/net5.0/Slimulator /home/john/Projects/Slimulator/test_mazes/small-maze-food2.png
Loading file /home/john/Projects/Slimulator/test_mazes/small-maze-food2.png
Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Cannot found the default FFmpeg directory.
On Windows you have to set "FFmpegLoader.FFmpegPath" with full path to the directory containing FFmpeg shared build ".dll" files
For more informations please see https://github.com/radek-k/FFMediaToolkit#setup
   at FFMediaToolkit.FFmpegLoader.LoadFFmpeg()
   at FFMediaToolkit.Encoding.Internal.OutputContainer.Create(String extension)
   at FFMediaToolkit.Encoding.MediaBuilder..ctor(String path, Nullable`1 format)
   at FFMediaToolkit.Encoding.MediaBuilder.CreateContainer(String path)
   at Slimulator.AnimationBuffer..ctor(String videoPath, Int32 height, Int32 width, Int32 frameRate) in /home/john/Projects/Slimulator/AnimationBuffer.cs:line 11
   at Slimulator.Simulation..ctor(Space space, String seed, String outputVideoPath) in /home/john/Projects/Slimulator/Simulation.cs:line 12
   at Slimulator.Launcher.Main(String[] args) in /home/john/Projects/Slimulator/Launcher.cs:line 8

Process finished with exit code 134.
```

When I go to https://github.com/radek-k/FFMediaToolkit#setup I find just this:

> Linux - Download FFmpeg using your package manager.
>
> You need to set FFmpegLoader.FFmpegPath with a full path to FFmpeg libraries.
>
> If you want to use 64-bit FFmpeg, you have to disable the Build -> Prefer 32-bit option in
> Visual Studio project properties.

I have already installed `FFmpeg` package via pacman and I am still getting these error.

How can I fix this so I can use `FFMediaToolkit` without problem on linux ?
Thank you for help

**EDIT1:** I use Arch linux.
**EDIT2:** There is related issue on github: https://github.com/radek-k/FFMediaToolkit/issues/80

Comment: READ THE ERROR MESSAGE.  It tell you exactly what is wrong and how to fix.

Comment: @jdweng I know what is wronf but I have no idea what to do about it

Comment: What distribution are we talking about? "Pacman" hint for Arch, Manjaro, ... ?

Comment: @Fildor I use arch linux

Comment: And you installed [ffmpeg-full](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ffmpeg-full/) from AUR?

Comment: Have you tried to issue `updatedb` and then `locate ffmpeg` in a terminal?

Comment: The error says : On Windows you have to set "FFmpegLoader.FFmpegPath" with full path to the directory containing FFmpeg shared build ".dll" files
For more informations please see https://github.com/radek-k/FFMediaToolkit#setup

Comment: If you follow the link, it says you have to use FFmpegLoader.FFmpegPath to set the path without the mention of a specific OS ...

Comment: So I called `which ffmpeg`  and it gave me `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`.  so I added `FFmpegLoader.FFmpegPath = "/usr/bin/";` at begging of my project and it just returned:

`Unable to load DLL 'avutil.56 under /usr/bin/': The specified module could not be found.`

I will try to install the `ffmpeg-full` package if it helps.

Comment: @Fildor Installing `ffmpeg-full` did not help. Still thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @Fildor Can I please ask you how to find ffmpeg shared build (or how is called the directory refered in error)?

Comment: tbh, I have no idea. I would have expected `which ffmpeg` to spit out a maybe little awkward path, so it couldn't be found. And I also expected this to be fixed by using `FFmpegLoader.FFmpegPath` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to set:

```java
FFmpegLoader.FFmpegPath = "/usr/lib/";
```

because arch linux has different installation location than other distributions.